# Extracting values from json file android

Tags: android, json

My json string is as follows:

i pass it to a json object as follows but i get only the golfs value.

```
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(details_circuit);
        System.out.println("jsonObject "+jsonObject.toString());
        jsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golfs");
```

if i do

```
        jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("circuit"));
```

i cannot get any value. Any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject   jsonObject = new JSONObject(details_circuit);

JSONObject circuit=jsonObject.getJSONObject("circuit");
int id=circuit.getInt("@id");
int version=circuit.getInt("@version");
String name=circuit.getString("@name");
String description=circuit.getString("@description");

JSONObject row;
int id ;
int version;
String name;
JSONArray golfs=jsonObject.getJSONObject("golfs");
for(int i=0;i<golfs.length();i++){
 row = golfs.getJSONObject(i);
 id = row.getInt("id");
version=row.getInt("@version");
name=row.getString("@name");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("circuit"));//Wrong because circuit is a jsonObject
```

Use this instead

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("circuit");
```

or use

```
JSONObject circuit = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get('circuit');
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

`"circuit": {` is a JSONObject

Change to

```
 jsonObject1 = (JSONObject)jsonObject.getJSONObject("circuit");
 int id = jsonObject1.getInt("@id"):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("circuit");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
JSONObject json1 = json.getJSONObject("circuit");
int id = json1.getInt("id");
```

For JsonArray Use following.

```
JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("golfs");
JSONObject jarray = json.getJSONObject(0);
int id = json1.getInt("id");
```